# How do I scale/standardize one set of data that is non-linear (due to temp variations in a device) to that of a data set that is linear?

Tags: multidimensional-scaling, calibration

I have data from two instruments over time. One of the instruments does not show a linear trend due to an anomaly but I want to standardize that data against that of the second instrument because I can rely on it and will use this algorithm in the future. Here is how the data looks[image]

Comment: This question sounds like "I have bad data, and I know they're bad, and I know why they're bad; how do I use these bad data?"  Is it possible to fix the problem that produced the bad data, and produce new (good) data?  If so, that's probably going to work much better than trying to correct for the problem downstream in your data analysis.

Comment: Hi Dan, the data collected in itself isn't bad but the skew happens whenever the instrument gets above a certain temp. So, if I can linearize the data according to the standard, I will be able to keep on using this instrument.

Comment: Your question assumes that there's a substantial source of uncorrected error in the data — i.e., that your data are bad.  Can you insulate or cool the instrument so that its temperature doesn't get too high?  Or, if not, maybe you could record temperature data at the same time as your primary data, then use the temperature data to correct the primary data?  My basic point is that it's probably better to think of this as an instrument problem, not a data analysis problem.

Comment: The temp data looks exactly like the data about and I understand where you are coming from; however, it is a radiance measuring instrument that does that part of data collection correctly so, unfortunately we cannot replace the instrument (too expensive!). I need to be able to automate the process since we have the data from another device that can be used as a standard.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend the second option: collect temperature data at the same time.  Then a simple model might look like $y_{blue} = y_{red} + err_{temp} + err$, where $err_{temp}$ is a function of temperature and $err$ is all other error.  (This is similar to @Sam's answer.)  For some more sophisticated approaches, read up on [measurement error models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models).

Answer (score 1):

If you really know the skew, as I believe you claim to do, you should just be able to remove it.

Because your observations are:

$X_i = Y_i + skew(Y_i) + noise_i$

Where $Y_i$ is the ground truth (the true value on your y-axis) and $X_i$ is the observation (the observed value on your y-axis). So if you can find a model on $skew(Y_i)$ that you believe is good, I'd say be just subtracting that from $X_i$ you should be fine. This however only works if you assume that $skew(Y_i)$ is a deterministic function - otherwise your results (for example if you want to use it in OLS), will not be accurate.

But this is making a lot of assumptions, and I don't really see where you would want to know this from, so I'd proceed with caution, depending on what it is that you really want to find out. If for example you are assuming that the blue dots stem from a smooth function and all you'd want to do is find an estimate for the irreducible error in your data, you might get away with fitting a smoother, subtracting the smoother, and then at least you'd have an estimate of the irreducible error on each single data point, if that helps you.

Comment: Thank you Sam.....I was thinking along the second option too. I was going to model the blue data on a curve and try to manipulate it to linearize in using ratios from the trendline in the orange dataspread. I am just not awfully  familiar techniques, so I was trying to figure out what would an expert opinion suggest.